# Automated test cases for AWS using aws-sdk-mock

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-mock

I am trying to test the automation of tagging and untagging of resources in AWS. This is very easy to do with the apis but i want to be able to do the same with aws-sdk-mock but i am having trouble understanding the documentation of aws-sdk-mock as to how this would work.

I have the following code in which i am trying to assign a tag with `key = 'ABC:DEF'` and `value = 'v1:TestLambda:dev:web:Test:None'` to sample rds instance named `'sample-instance`'

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const AWSMock = require('aws-sdk-mock');   
var rdsparams = {
    ResourceName: 'arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:{account-id}:db:sample-instance', 
    /* required */
    Tags: [ /* required */
    {
        Key: 'ABC:DEF',
        Value: 'v1:TestLambda:dev:web:Test:None'
    },
    /* more items */
    ]
};

AWSMock.mock('RDS', 'addTagsToResource', function (params, callback){
        callback(null, "successfully added tag to resource");
      });
```

I would like to assign the tag to the rds instance. Is this the correct way of doing this because i get no output on the command line?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no errors but i am not getting any output. How can i check if tags were successfully added to RDS?

Comment: Try this line `AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS)` in your code before mocking resources.

Comment: That helped. Thanks. Do you know how to do a listTagsForResource using AWSMock and only listing tags if they were added previously using addTagsToResource? If they were not added or the ResourceName is different then test should not pass?

Comment: This is mocking of resources, so mock the behavior you want to test.